# error while compiling curl library

Tags: linux, gcc, curl, glibc

I have this error message while building the `curl` library:

> libssl.a(s2_clnt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not
>   be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

I tried to use the `-fPIC` switch - nothing helps. The `openssl` library was before compiled without any error. `make check` passed as well.

Info: I am compiling `curl` against another version of `glibc` - the include path is provided in `./configure` with the `$CPPFLAGS` and `$LDFLAGS` == `-L/usr/glibc-2.22/lib` [== this is the path to the new `glibc` version]

**This error is thrown only when I compile it with the new `glibc` version.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for the issue collection I had in the past days:
[several make issues...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35096912/make-curl-with-different-glibc-version-unresolved-glibc-private)

Answer (score 1):

You get this kind of error when one object is built with hidden symbols and another one isn't.

Since I see you're trying to link a .a archive file aka static library, I assume that static library was built with different hidden symbol options than what you're using with curl.

I think that you can also get this when one object is using PIC and the other one isn't. To fix that compile the static library and curl with the same PIC settings.