# make curl with different glibc version: unresolved GLIBC_PRIVATE

Tags: gcc, curl, cuda, makefile, glibc

The distribution `glibc` version is 2.11.3. I compiled the version 2.22 into `/usr/glibc/`.

Running `make` for a new `curl` version 7.46 I receive this errors:

```
/usr/glibc/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__mktemp@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/glibc/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__tfind@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/glibc/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__tdelete@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/glibc/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__twalk@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/glibc/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__call_tls_dtors@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/glibc/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__madvise@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/glibc/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
/usr/glibc/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__getrlimit@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/glibc/lib/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__sendmmsg@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/glibc/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__ctype_init@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/glibc/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__h_errno@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/glibc/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__tsearch@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
/usr/glibc/lib/libpthread.so.0: undefined reference to `__libc_vfork@GLIBC_PRIVATE'
```

I am convinced it must be a problem because of the new `glibc` version but my linux knowledge is too weak to provide the correct path to the new `glibc` version.

What am I doing wrong? Thx!

Comment: @EmployedRussian The question may be a  "part" duplicate of your answer but my answer shows the case was more difficult because I had to differ the build paths for the other libraries. I do not mind if the question is marked as duplicated but my answer covers more. And yes, definitely, your answer helped to solve the link problem in CUDA NSight but I had to resolve the issues first which are not really covered by your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There were several issues:**

1. `glibc` 2.22 - distribution version is 2.11.3
2. `openssl` 1.0.2f - distribution version is 0.9.8j [from 2009!]
3. `curl` 7.46.0 - distribution version is 7.19.7
4. `libmemcached` with active `sasl` version from distribution

I am using all these libraries in my CUDA project and due the fact I wanted to update all these libraries to the newest version these steps were to do:

1. `glibc`: build into `/usr/glibc`
2. `openssl`: build into `/usr/glibc/openssl-curl/`. Before run `export $LDFLAGS=-L/usr/glibc/lib`
3. `curl`: run `./configure --prefix=/usr/glibc/openssl-curl/ --with-ssl=/usr/glibc/openssl-curl/ --disable-ldap` - **very important:** `$LDFLAGS` must be empty when running `configure` because the script adds the value to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and due the version mismatch of the new `glibc` and the distribution version all programs crash with `segmentation fault`. Before `make` run again `export $LDFLAGS=-L/usr/glibc/lib`.
4. For my project I had also to rebuild `libmemcached` with the new `glibc` version with this command: `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libmemcached --disable-sasl`

In CUDA I have to set the path to the new libraries and now all works. It is also very important the linker options `-Wl,--rpath=/usr/glibc/lib` and `-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/usr/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` are set in order the new `glibc` version is loaded.

For my linux system I **must not** add in `/etc/ld.so.conf` the path `/usr/glibc/lib` otherwise the whole system crashes.